# How can I get VSCODE Pico-go and CircuitPython extension commands to work

Tags: visual-studio-code, adafruit-circuitpython

I have installed `pico-go` extension in `VSCode`. When I do any `View>Command Palette>Pico-Go > Help > Show Pico Pin Map...` I always get Command `'Pico-Go > Help > Show Pico Pin Map'` resulted in an error (command `'picogo.extra.pins'` not found).

I get a similar error for any `pico-go` command. I have installed different versions of the Pico-go code, did restart after each and the problem is exhibited in all the versions I have tested. Pico-go states that it is dependent on `Python 3` and `Python3.9.1` that is installed and running in VSCode.

I have the same problem using `CircuitPython` commands on both systems. The Dependencies list includes Python and Juypter which are both installed.

I have a second system that has pico-go installed and it works properly. I do not know how to isolate what is wrong in the first system.

Even if I get this problem solved the getting started code

```
from machine import Pin
import time

pin = Pin(25, Pin.out)
while True:
    pin.toggle()
    time.sleep_ms(1000)
```

fails with

```
  File "e:\code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from machine import Pin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'
```

Comment: There is no `machine` module in CircuitPython. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you click the RUN that's at the bottom of the screen (in the window border) and not the tempting one at the top. The one at the top will run your Python code on your computer, which doesn't know what the Machine any other Pico-specific library is. The one at the bottom sends the code to the Pico and runs it there - you can confirm because "Pico Console" will be listed and not "Python".